# How to Add Created Table(s) into a Created Database in SQL+?

Tags: sql

After creating my database:

(example) CREATE DATABASE my_db;

How would you go about inserting a table that you have created into your Database?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how you would go about migrating tables from on database to another, I am sure you could look up creating SQL dump files for whatever product you are using.

If you just want to create a new table into the database you just created, something like: `USE my_db;
CREATE TABLE my_table{...}`

would do the job.

Hope this helped.